# How to use os.startfile with a button command (TkInter)

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to implement a button onto a canvas which opens a `.pdf` file when clicked.

My attempt is as follows

```
self.B3 = Button(InputFrame,text='Graphical Plots', command = os.startfile('Bessel.pdf'),bd=5,width=13,font="14")
self.B3.grid(column =0,row=3)
```

Unfortunately my code opens the `.pdf` file before I have clicked the button, as soon as it has run. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Python processes those two lines, it sees this in the first:

```
os.startfile('Bessel.pdf')
```

and interprets it as a valid function call.  So, it calls the function.

To fix the problem, define a function to handle the click event before that line and then assign the button's `command` opion to it:

```
def handler():
    # The code in here is "hidden"
    # It will only run when the function is called (the button is clicked)
    os.startfile('Bessel.pdf')
self.B3 = Button(InputFrame, text='Graphical Plots', command=handler, bd=5, width=13, font="14")
```

---

Or, even better/cleaner in this case, use a [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) (anonymous function):

```
self.B3 = Button(InputFrame, text='Graphical Plots', command=lambda: os.startfile('Bessel.pdf'), bd=5, width=13, font="14")
```

---

Or, as @J.F.Sebastian noted, you can use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
self.B3 = Button(InputFrame, text='Graphical Plots', command=functools.partial(os.startfile, "Bessel.pdf"), bd=5, width=13, font="14")
```

Note that you will have to import `functools` first.

Comment: 3rd option is `functools.partial(os.startfile, "Bessel.pdf")`