# Disabling buttons after click in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a simple application using Tkinter.

```
def appear(x):
    return lambda: results.insert(END, x)

letters=["A", "T", "D", "M", "E", "A", "S", "R", "M"] 

for index in range(9): 
    n=letters[index] 
    nButton = Button(buttons, bg="White", text=n, width=5, height=1,
    command =appear(n), relief=GROOVE).grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=index%3,
    column=index/3)
```

What I'm trying to do is disable the buttons once I click them.
I tried

```
def appear(x):
    nButton.config(state="disabled")
    return lambda: results.insert(END, x)
```

But it gives me the following error:

> NameError: global name 'nButton' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

2. Whenever you create widgets dynamically, you need to store references to them in a collection so that you can access them later.
3. The `grid` method of a Tkinter widget always returns `None`.  So, you need to put any calls to `grid` on their own line.
4. Whenever you assign a button's `command` option to a function that requires arguments, you must use a [`lambda`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why) or such to "hide" that call of the function until the button is clicked.  For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20556892/2555451.

Below is a sample script addressing all of these issues:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, GROOVE

root = Tk()

def appear(index, letter):
    # This line would be where you insert the letter in the textbox
    print letter

    # Disable the button by index
    buttons[index].config(state="disabled")

letters=["A", "T", "D", "M", "E", "A", "S", "R", "M"]

# A collection (list) to hold the references to the buttons created below
buttons = []

for index in range(9): 
    n=letters[index]

    button = Button(root, bg="White", text=n, width=5, height=1, relief=GROOVE,
                    command=lambda index=index, n=n: appear(index, n))

    # Add the button to the window
    button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=index%3, column=index/3)

    # Add a reference to the button to 'buttons'
    buttons.append(button)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a button after clicking you can make a function in which you will do the desired operation but in the start you should a command to disable the button so that as the function runs it desables the button .
if you want you can take a little bit help with this code:-

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def disable_button():
    button_1['state'] = DISABLED
    print("this is how you disable a buuton after a click")
button_1 = Button(root,text = "Disable this button",command=disable_button)
button_1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**I hope your problem has been solved**

**Thanks**

Answer (score -1):

This was very helpful for a work I'm currently working on, to add a minor correction

```
from math import floor



button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=index%3, column=floor(index/3))
```

Comment: Is this a solution?